# disable kendo mvc dropdownlist using checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a checkbox that should enable Kendo MVC DropdownList when checked and diable DropdownList when unchecked. But I can't do, there is a problem. Can you suggest how can I resolve this issue.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="if (this.checked) { document.getElementById('ParentDeptDrp').disabled = true; } else { document.getElementById('ParentDeptDrp').disabled = false; }" />
            Is Product/Service?
            <br />        
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("ParentDeptDrp") 
                .DataTextField("DeptName") 
                .DataValueField("DeptName") 
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                       source.Read(read =>
                       {
                            read.Action("GetParentDeptt", "Department"); 
                       })
                       .ServerFiltering(true); 
                })
                .SelectedIndex(1) 
                //.Enable(false)

            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function setDDL(chk){
       var dropdownlist = $("#ParentDeptDrp").data("kendoDropDownList");
       dropdownlist.enable(chk); 
};
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="setDDL(this.checked);" />
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-enable